# Return the highest and lowest number of a given string - Javascript

Tags: javascript

*In this little assignment you are given a string of space separated numbers, and have to return the highest and lowest number.*

I know I can find dozens of solution and examples of this one, but I have a case that I really can not figure it out and I would like to know why.

This is the code

```js
highAndLow = numbers => {
  var smallestElement = numbers[0];
  var highestElement = numbers[0];
  numbers = numbers.split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] < smallestElement) {
      smallestElement = numbers[i];
    }
    console.log(`${numbers[i]} > ${highestElement}`);
    if (numbers[i] > highestElement) {
      console.log('----------------------------');
      highestElement = numbers[i];
    }
  }

  return `${highestElement} ${smallestElement}`;
};

console.log(highAndLow('4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 12'));
```

Considering the example above, my result should be `542 -214`, however I get `6 -214`.

I put two `console.log` that would print `-----------------` when conditions is true, but when I look at the output

[image]

How does `if(6 > 542)` return `true` ?

Comment: Hint: `"6" > "542"`

Comment: `parseInt` before compare

Comment: aah makes sense, thanks.

Comment: You can use `map` to start with an array of numbers.  Make your first line `numbers = numbers.split(' ').map(x=> Number(x));` and things should make more sense

Comment: @IrkenInvader Or just `.map(Number)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting `6` as highest value is because when you are doing `if (numbers[i] > highestElement)` it is comparing string not a number, and in string `6` is greater than `54` as it compares character by character. so change `if (numbers[i] > highestElement)` to `if (+numbers[i] > +highestElement)`(+ will convert string to number)

```js
highAndLow = numbers => {
  var smallestElement = numbers[0];
  var highestElement = numbers[0];
  numbers = numbers.split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (+numbers[i] < +smallestElement) {
      smallestElement = numbers[i];
    }
    console.log(`${numbers[i]} > ${highestElement}`);
    if (+numbers[i] > +highestElement) {
      console.log('----------------------------');
      highestElement = numbers[i];
    }
  }

  return `${highestElement} ${smallestElement}`;
};

console.log(highAndLow('4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 12'));
```

Comment: I couldn't realize I was using strings : ) also thanks for the + trick, didn't know it converts from int to string

Comment: @Seinfeld _it converts from int to string_ not true, reverse is true(FYI there is no int in js)

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing string.Instead you can split the string into an array and use map function to convert each element to integer. Then use `sort` which will arrange the array and then `Math.max/min` to get the values

```js
highAndLow = function(x) {
  // split the string & map function to convert each element to number
  var newArray = x.split(' ').map(function(item) {
    return Number(item)
  })

  return {
    max: Math.max(...newArray),
    min: Math.min(...newArray),
  }
};

console.log(highAndLow('4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 12'));
```

Comment: Can I ask what exactly is the task of the three dots ?

Comment: @YazeedZaid those are called [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)